# number of mod-3 monotone functions

Tags: combinatorics, functions

I am looking for the number of mod-3 monotone functions of 1 variable. I am either using the wrong search criteria or there is no work on this particular area.
A function f is called mod-3 monotone iff a <= b => f(a) <= f(b) for all values of a and b in mod-3.

Comment: What is the definition you are working with? (What is a $\bmod\!-3$ monotone function?)

Comment: Functions as sets or as groups?  Is the ordering is simply $\overline{0} < \overline{1} < \overline{2}$?  Also do you mean monotone or strictly monotone?

Comment: This is similar to the definition of monotone boolean functions related to the Dedekind numbers. I mean monotone not strictly monotone. @AlexR

Comment: @RodrigoA.Obando I'm sorry but I can't quite follow you. Would you mind giving a precise, self-contained definition in the question? (_A function $f: A\to B$ is called mod-3 monotone iff$\ldots$_)

Comment: Certainly. A function f is called mod-3 monotone iff a <= b => f(a) <= f(b) for all values of a and b in mod-3.